# ASP.NET toolkit Accordion double click issue

Tags: gridview, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I am using a accordion control which has nested gridviews within the content section and a series of buttons. When the page is first loaded, it requires 2 clicks before any button or linkbutton's events are fired.

For the buttons I have hacked together a fix using external buttons which I invoke via javascript, however for the gridview 'edit' and 'delete' command buttons this does not apply.

Has anyone found a solution for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I guess the accordion control had a bug in it that caused this. Check out this link http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=11055 for the updated code to fix this. It handled it in my case after searching and debugging for a couple hours.